# Sorting in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have some strings like

```
"999"
"555"
"7777"
"CC44"
"AAAA"
"BBBB"
```

How can I sort so that the output will be

```
"999"
"7777"
"555"
"AAAA"
"BBBB"
"CC44"
```

The rule is : Based on the string's numeric value in ascending order

I have included the script too

```
declare @tbl  Table(
    data VARCHAR(MAX)   
)

INSERT INTO @tbl (data)

SELECT '999' UNION ALL
SELECT '555' UNION ALL
SELECT '7777' UNION ALL
SELECT 'CC44' UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAAA' UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBBB'
```

Comment: are they the exact string in your database? if so, can i assume that there are 3 types, numbers, alphabets and alphabets + numbers?

Comment: What are the **actual** rules you want to apply? What about spaces? 777 vs 7777? 7711 vs 7777 vs 77AA?

Comment: (Why does `999` come before `7777` but `555` after? :-/)

Comment: @pst: string length. But still need rules...

Comment: Rule: Based on the string's numeric value

Comment: *What* rule? DESCENDING numeric first? ASCENDING mixed after? Something RANDOM? Because `7777` is longer than `999` or `555`. The "rules" need to be defined first. E.g. why is it not `555`, `999`, `7777`?

Comment: It is in Ascending order

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar_2 No it is not. Please review your output and define "numeric value".

Comment: What @pst said; I can't figure out what you mean by 'numeric value' here, based on your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but:

```
select col where IsNumeric(col)=1

order by IsNumeric(col) asc, col
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a natural sort order, so you might need to add another column to perform the sorting.  If that isn't possible, you will need to split the data set, sort each half, and rejoin them.

```
SELECT data FROM tbl WHERE columnname > "0" AND columnname < "9999" ORDER BY columnname DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT data FROM tbl WHERE columnname < "9999"
ORDER BY columnname ASC
```

Comment: error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: Union can only have one `order by` You can solve this by an sequencebut sql server not have sequence, then:1 create user sequence, 2. use temp table.